# I have a unrecognized command in my powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have an issue in my powershell. The issue is when I type the follow commad "pip --version" and the poweshell show me that the command is not recognized.
And I want to understand why because all the commands was working just fine.

I tried this;

[image]

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Images of code are useless to us (especially those that are unreadable). See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should not post images of code or errors, and then come back and [edit] your post to include the code as text, copied and pasted into your post.

Comment: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an environment variable to the pip script folder has to be set.

See here:

[How to install packages with pip in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963446/how-to-install-packages-with-pip-in-windows-powershell)